# Php Upload multiple files and rename it if not equal at foreach

Tags: php, file-upload

Im trying to upload multiple files example:

```
foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
        {
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
            {
                $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];

                move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/var/uploads/'.$product_id . "/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);

            }
        }
```

Ok now the files are in the server as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg.. till 24.jpg

Then now Im doing a for each for check if the files that I upload got the name that I want if not rename it.

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/var/uploads/' . $product_id . "/";
        $files = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

        foreach($files as $i => $name) 
        {


            $newname = sprintf($directory . "%d.jpg", $i+1);

            if ($newname != $i + 1) 
            {
                rename($name, $newname);
            }
        }
```

The problem now is that when I rename them I got this result

[image]

Why 2.jpg, 3.jpg , 4.jpg till 9.jpg disapear?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :)

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/var/uploads/' . $product_id . "/";
        $files = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

        $i = 1;

        foreach($files as $e => $name) 
        {

            $newname = $directory . $i . ".jpg";

            if($name != $newname)
            {
                rename($name, $newname);

            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

            $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/var/uploads/' . $product_id . "/";

$i = 1;


while (false !== ($file = readdir($directory)))
{
   // check extension
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'jpg')
    {

        $newName = $i . '.jpg';
        rename($file, $newName);//rename file

        $i++;
    }
}


closedir($directory)
```

Comment: But If I upload 24 files with different name It keep it with different name, dont rename it to 1.jpg, 2.jpg till 24.

Comment: Maybe its because I got  readdir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource and closedir(): supplied argument is not a valid Directory resource? Thank you in advance!